# Getting The Memory Address Of A DLL Function

Tags: c, windows, winapi, memory, dll

I want to know if it is possible, using C and the WindowsAPI, if there is a function that will get me the 32 bit(I think) memory address of a function in a dll. For example. How do I get the 32 bit $xxxxxxxx address of Beep() in kernel32.dll. Secondly, if I use the memory address instead of the function name in assembly, can I avoid linking. For example

```
mov eax, $xxxxxxxx
```

instead of

```
mov eax, Beep
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This program will print the address of `Beep` in kernel32:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    HMODULE hMod = GetModuleHandle("kernel32.dll");
    void* fn = GetProcAddress(hMod, "Beep");
    printf("%p", fn);
}
```

I omitted error checking for the sake of simplicity. In a real program you would not do so.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Look up 'GetProcAddress' on MSDN.

Comment: IMO, this is the most correct way to avoid static linkage. It's the standard way for 'old' apps to access new OS features without linking to the newer OS API libs.