# How do I enforce my application binary to be able to spawn only one thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading

I want to make an example program of a rare bug and it requires that my program shall not be able to spawn more than one thread. At least this will be helpful to enforce a policy on the background C++ threading implementations. This is on windows, Visual Studio 2017 environment. Do you know how to do such?

The example code is using *std::async* and such STL codes, which are depending on the environment and I wanted to simulate one simply on my platform which will not start more than one thread.

Comment: Threading is a operating system feature, you can not prevent an app to request a new thread with [CreateThread](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createthread) system call (standard library std::thread is a wrapper on top of this system call). However, if you app not creating any additional threads - windows will create only one thread to it. I.e. `#include <cstdio> int main(int argc, const char** argv) { std::printf("Hello world!"); }` will use only one thread.

Comment: Thanks, of course, but that's not gonna make it for me.

Comment: I will try to dedicate my process to one core, hopefully it will trigger the bug easily, if not instantly

Comment: unless you specifically ask for it your application will not start new threads. If you want only one thread, then just dont start new ones

Comment: If you really want to you could theoretically create your own CreateThread function and have it call the original CreateThread function (by using it's address) only the first time it's called. It would not limit it as much as resolving the original address would still be possible, but it would make it much harder, you'd have to do this in an `extern "C"` block to make sure C calls are also redirected through your function. But what @formerlyknownas_463035818 said is the best idea in my opinion.

Comment: Can you just call `std::async(std::launch::deferred, ...)` instead, which doesn't create new threads to run the task? By default I think the MSVC `std::async` will use Windows thread pools. It's possible to limit the maximum number of threads in a pool, but I don't know if you can get the handle to the pool used by `std::async` in order to change its properties.

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21384066/getting-the-memory-address-of-a-dll-function to find out how you can resolve the original address of a function your program reimplemented.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visual C++ - overriding a function imported from a DLL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9566468/visual-c-overriding-a-function-imported-from-a-dll)

Comment: xception, did you read the question at all? It doesn't have anything to do with DLL imports.